# Dynamic POST Radio Button

Tags: post, radio-button

I create, dynamically, groups ou radio button in the "jQuery(document).ready(function())".

The partial code is:
(...)                                               texto_html = texto_html + "**"+record.descricao_equipamento+":**"+record.nome_fornecedor+" ("+record.preco_equip_fornecedor+"€)";
(...)
The output is ok, one example:

```
<h5 class=""><strong>Transmissor 1:</strong></h5>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label"></label>
<div class="controls">
    <label class="radio line">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios11" value="11">Texto 1
    </label>
</div>
</div>

<h5 class=""><strong>Transmissor 2:</strong></h5>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label"></label>
<div class="controls">
<label class="radio line">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios12" value="120">
    Texto 2
</label>
<label class="radio line">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios12" value="12">
    Text 3
</label>
</div>
```

Now I want to POST my Form with AJAX (data: $("#myForm").serialize(),(..)
My problem is in my php file (that will retrieve the Posted values). How can I know how many radios groups I have? Is there a way to serialize them with, let's say an array of radios? Because really I just want their value, independently if they belong to group1 or group2 ou whatever.
thank you.
I'm stuck here! :)))

Comment: why do you need to know how many radio groups you have?

Comment: In this case, the posted values can be obtained: "$valor = $_POST['optionsRadios11']". Is this correct? Is there a way to see all the serialize() string?

Comment: How can I see the serialized data? I try this: console.log($("#MyForm").serialize()); But I didn't get nothing. I'm using the console.log correctly?

Comment: If none radio is checked, the result will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to iterate over all the radios that were sent:

I can think of two ways of doing that:

1. You can iterate over all the $_POST values and filter them by a regex (to get just the "optionsRadiosXX" ones)
2. you can also append a new parameter in your http post (after form.serialize) with all the radios under a given form and then use this parameter as a guide in your php.

.

```
var getRadios = function() {
    var map = {};
    $("#formID input[type=radio]").each(function(){
        var e = $(this);
        if(!map[e.attr("name")]) {
            map[e.attr("name")] = true;
        }
    });

    var a = []
    for(var r in map) {
        a.push(r); 
    }

    //  alert(JSON.stringify(a));   
    return a;
}
```

See here an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IKayC

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks deantoni, That's it! I think I get your point, but I'm a dummie in programming and have to study a little bit. I tried your example and this returns me all the radio names. I think I can do it with your example. Now I have something to do. Back to php... :))) Thank you once more. Regards

Comment: you're welcome! just make sure to accept the answer if that helped you! thanks :)